# TCP Connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed.RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, rabbitmqctl

I have three servers I am trying to add to a cluster.

- bus01,
- bus02,
- bus03

When I try to run any command in bus02 or bus03 I am getting the following error:

> DIAGNOSTICS
>
> attempted to contact: [rabbit@bus02]
>
> rabbit@bus02:
>
> - connected to epmd (port 4369) on bus02 epmd reports node 'rabbit' usese
> - port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic TCP connection
> - succeeded but Erlang distribution failede
> - Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie

Everywhere I read mentions that the erlang.cookie is out of sync and they should be the same across servers.

I have copied the .erlang.cookie file from bus01 to bus02 & bus03. I have two copies on this file on each server. They all contain the same hash value in the .cookie file and all servers and file locations.

- C:\Users\%User%
- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile

Even after all this running `rabbitmqctl status` on either bus02 or bus03 throw the above error.

I cannot see what I am missing here.

Comment: The topic you need to explore is "distributed erlang".  Check out this doc to see if it gives you some ideas: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html.  Also see other questions similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759737/getting-rabbitmq-authentication-failing-even-with-cookie-is-set
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893899/authentication-failed-rejected-by-the-remote-node-please-check-the-erlang-coo

Comment: Run a checksum on the `.erlang.cookie` file to ensure they are _identical_. Also, after copying the file RabbitMQ must be restarted to read the new value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while creating a cluster in rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408827/error-while-creating-a-cluster-in-rabbitmq)